# Azure SQL Performance bad when dealing with SELECT and INSERT on same Table with 21Mil records

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

We have Azure hosted solution where function-app is inserting records into Azure SQL. We have one such Azure function where we first do a SELECT Query (simple with indexed column used in the filter criteria to check if the record exists). If no record found then we insert into the same table. This is working all fine when we have less than 1000 records in the table but now the table has 21Million records and a simple SELECT statement takes about 25 seconds when called from the function app when there is load of 100 concurrent users. My suspicion here is the SELECT and INSERT is part of same function app method call and I think somewhere there are locks happening on the Table that's causing the SELECT statement to take 25 seconds. We do see Compute utlization hitting 80% during that time.

I am sure many may have experienced similar issue, anyways to work around this issue where we are doing SELECT and INSERT in same transaction set and avoiding the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an "insert where not exists" style problem. This post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/the-insert-if-not-exists-challenge-a-solution/ should help you solve it.

BTW, use of the query planner is really helpful in situations like this, because it will show you what is going on and how long it takes so you don't have to speculate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: Thank you @james-mcpherson appreciate your suggestion above. I will look into using the principles above and report back if that resolves the issue! thank you agian.

Comment: Thank you @James your suggestion on using MERGE helped us a lot to improve the performance now same operation is executed in less than 50 ms.